# Avoid The Divide by Zero Error Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to calculate some stats on my Laravel site...however when I execute the following code it is giving me a 'Divide By Zero Error'

I understand why because there are no records so the calculation is 0 divide 0

Is there a way that if it eqauls zero to echo '0' rather than throw up that error

Controlller

```
    private function getAverageOddsForLastMonth()
{
    $firstDayOfLastMonth = new Carbon('first day of last month');
    $lastDayOfLastMonth = new Carbon('last day of last month');

    $tipslastmonth = Tip::whereBetween('tip_date',
        [
            $firstDayOfLastMonth,
            $lastDayOfLastMonth
        ]
    )->count();

    $sumOfTheOddsLastMonth = Tip::whereBetween('tip_date',
        [
            $firstDayOfLastMonth,
            $lastDayOfLastMonth
        ]
    )->sum('odds');

    return ($sumOfTheOddsLastMonth / $tipslastmonth);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add a simple condition:

```
return $tipslastmonth == 0 ? 0 : ($sumOfTheOddsLastMonth / $tipslastmonth);
```

Answer (score 2):

- As you know, This error occurs Because of 0 in your Variable Simply you
  do this

```
if($tipslastmonth != 0)     
    $tipslastmonth = $sumOfTheOddsLastMonth / $tipslastmonth;  
else     
    $tipslastmonth = 0;
```

1. When 0 not occur else part will be executed work fine with my project

Comment: Thanks Kjartan improve my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an easy way.**

Rather than using a conditional clause to test for a zero value before every division operation, I use a **custom helper** to do this globally throughout my app and catch for division by zero. That way I don't have to worry if I got the screening code right in each place I use division, and I can globally turn it off or on easily for debugging. It's way easier than you would think.

**Create a blank file** in which you will have the custom functions you want universally available throughout your app, and name it `helpers.php`. I put mine in `app/Helpers/helpers.php` but many put theirs in `app/helpers.php` or `app/Http/helpers.php`. Doesn't matter as long as you **list it correctly in your `composer.json` autoload section** like so (showing my location):

```
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
  },
```

This just ensures that your universal helper functions are pre-loaded and available throughout your app. Once you save `composer.json`, do a `composer dump-autoload` in your command-line terminal to set it up.

In your new blank `helpers.php` file, simply **add the following**:

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('divnum')) {

        function divnum($numerator, $denominator)
        {
            return $denominator == 0 ? 0 : ($numerator / $denominator);
        }

    }
```

Correct protocol requires us to check to make sure there's not already a function in use with the same name as our new helper. It's not likely, but it you use a lot of packages you never know - best to check to be safe. Hence, we start with a **check for the existence of our new function name**.

Our function `divnum()` now **simply divides any two numbers we give it**, making sure that if the denominator (the dividing number) is zero, that we don't do the division and instead return an answer of zero. If the denominator is safe (!=0) then return the correct division answer. That way we avoid crashing with a division-by-zero error.

**Use it like so:**

```
$answer = divnum($number1, $number2);
```

**Examples:**

```
$answer = divnum(20,5);  //sets $answer variable to 4

$answer = divnum(20,0);  //sets $answer variable to 0
```

So where before you would get a division-by-zero error with the following:

```
$number1 = 2300;
$number2 = 0;
$answer = $number1/$number2;  //Your app crashes as you're dividing by zero
```

This is how you do division hereafter throughout your app:

```
$number1 = 2300;
$number2 = 0;
$answer = divnum($number1,$number2);  //Your app continues without error and $answer as zero
```

Once you set up this simple helper, the coding difference thereafter is negligible and you never have to worry about division by zero again.

Comment: This one is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ternary operator, it's enough.

```
$price = 100;
$qty = 0;
$total = $price / ($qty ? $qty : 1);
```